# How to improve strspn implementation

Tags: c, function, string.h

```
size_t my_strspn(const char *string, const char *chars)
{
    size_t n;
    const char *p;
    for (n = 0; *string; string++, n++)
    {
        for (p = chars; *p && *p != *string; p++);
        if (!*p)
            break;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Is there a simple way to remove "break"? I tried to modify for loops, but they make one extra iteration more that needed.

Comment: Not really. Without the `break;` statement, the `for` loop will reach its end, whatever the various conditions and flags and thus, reaching the end, the `n++` will execute.

Comment: So then it would be better to use `while` loops to avoid `break;` statement in this case?

Comment: Yeah, you could use a `while`, but then you'd have to separately initialize `n` before that loop. Nothing wrong with using `break;`, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, just my teacher demands implementation without `break;`, and he said it could be easily put inside loop conditions, but i haven't figured out how

Comment: Well, you *could* just replace `break;` with `return n;` - but that's maybe not in the 'spirit' of your teacher's question. :-)

Comment: He's against multiple `return` statements as well :-)

Comment: I'd turn the inner loop into an array lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing outer `for` loop with `while` loop, and adding `*p == *string` check which adds one to counter after the inner `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to this forum to add a comment and I'm too busy (i.e. lazy) to test this, so...

What about adding the *p check in the first for loop?:

```
for (n = 0; *string && *p; string++, n++)
```

Comment: This does not work, and that is why the question is asked, but thanks